# Doubts when using radio button group(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have a variable in my backing bean of type int:

```
private int myVariable;

//Get and set methods
```

What i want is to give to the variable above a different value depending on the radio button that is selected.

```
<h:selectOneRadio
            id="myComponent" value="#{myBackingBean.myVariable}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="7" itemLabel="Text 1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="Text 2" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="8" itemLabel="Text 3" />                       
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

How can **myVariable** have value 7 if the first item is selected, 12 if the second and 8 if the third?

Can i do this by changing my setter method?

How?

What is the easiest way?

Comment: *How can myVariable have value 7 if the first item is selected, 12 if the second and 8 if the third?* Do you want you just select and your variable should have the value, is it the question ?

Comment: What i want is to give to the variable a different int value depending on the selected radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have converter exactly for this purpose. [Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) it is demonstrated

Comment: Also see [jsf2.0 style converter](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. You don't need to do anything else. JSF/EL has already builtin converters (coercions) for standard value types boolean, integer, long, float and double. If you have a problem with it, it definitely lies somewhere else.